# In PHP how to check if hashed password match database password

Tags: php, mysql, hash

my problem is in the login page when the user login I get this error the sha256 function is not implement in mysql. Is there something wrong with my code or is is the sha2 not supported anymore. Is there other way to hash password in mysql.

> Warning: hash(): Unknown hashing algorithm: sha2

create_account.php

```
//create account 
 $query = "INSERT INTO mytable (username,fname,lname,country,age,gender,password)
    VALUES ('$username','$fname','$lname','$country',$age','$gender',SHA2('$password', 224))";
```

login.php

```
//check if password match 
$hased_password= hash("sha2", $password);
$hased_password= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$hashedPass);

  $query = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from mytable where password=  '$hased_password'  AND username='$username'");

 $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['username']=$username;  
$_SESSION['fname'] = $fname;
header("location: userPage.php");  
} else {
$error = "username or password is invalid";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: I would suggest using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://secure.php.net/password_hash) and [`password_verify()`](https://secure.php.net/password_verify) to manage passwords.

Comment: What about using `hash("sha2", $password);` before inserting record and pass the hash to the insert statement?

Comment: Also, `sha2` isn't a hashing algorithm, it's a *family* of algorithms.  You need to pick something like `sha256`, `sha512`, etc and make sure you use the *same* bit length in both PHP and MySQL.

Comment: @RocketHazmat oh I see , sha256 and sha512 are not supported I will try your suggestion

Comment: Too bad my Stack Overflow account is in the penalty box. I have not been able to ask question since I had about 400 points! But, I'm glad to help where I can. The tell me if I get enough points, that I can get out of the penalty box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I give the following answer with the best of intentions.

.
.
.

I would direct your attention here [PHP: Password Hashing Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php)

and ...

I would direct your attention here [PHP Manual: PDO Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

My advice would be to use nothing less than Blowfish for hashing your passwords. Also, you need to be conscious of timing attacks. Hence, just letting the database tell you whether or not a hashed password matches is an answer, but it is a poor answer, as failed attempts that are close can be measured in micro-seconds (especially since the Internet / network lies between the attacker and your system). The longer it takes to get the result back, the closer the attacking system knows (assumes) it is to having the correct hash.

(Remember, a string comparison goes character by character. It does not matter what the contents of the string are).

Attacks during an off peak time might yield the best results.

Use PDO prepared statements.

Use password_verify, inside the business logic layer to determine if the hashes match. Only use the database to retrieve a hash. Don't do business logic tasks at the data layer. Do not rely on a count of records. That is a short cut.